# Correct way to mount a host directory in a docker container using salt

Tags: docker, salt-stack

Using the command line below:

```
docker run -ti -v /hostDirectory:/containerDirectory
```

I can map a directory on the host to a directory on the container.

How do I get the same effect [using saltstack's dockerng](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.dockerng.html)? I don't see anywhere in the documentation referencing the host volume directory mapping to a directory on the container, it looks like dockerng only supports volumes created using docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant parameter in dockerng was renamed to 'binds' under the dockerng.running function

```
binds
Files/directories to bind mount. Each bind mount should be passed in the format <host_path>:<container_path>:<read_only>, where <read_only> is one of rw (for read-write access) or ro (for read-only access).

foo:
  dockerng.running:
    - image: bar/baz:latest
    - binds: /srv/www:/var/www:ro,/etc/foo.conf:/usr/local/etc/foo.conf:rw
Binds can be passed as a YAML list instead of a comma-separated list:

foo:
  dockerng.running:
    - image: bar/baz:latest
    - binds:
      - /srv/www:/var/www:ro
      - /home/myuser/conf/foo.conf:/etc/foo.conf:rw
Optionally, the read-only information can be left off the end and the bind mount will be assumed to be read-write. The example below is equivalent to the one above:

foo:
  dockerng.running:
    - image: bar/baz:latest
    - binds:
      - /srv/www:/var/www:ro
      - /home/myuser/conf/foo.conf:/etc/foo.conf
```